# symfony session order Binding entities to query parameters only allowed for entities that have an identifier

Tags: symfony

I need to get all information about an order for my e-commerce but I get this error
Need your help
I'm using session

The message is not long

**Binding entities to query parameters only allowed for entities that have an identifier.**
**ORMInvalidArgumentException**

Thanks for your help

I will post my entity file just in few seconds
just below

```
   <?php

    namespace Gba\GbaBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
    use Gba\GbaBundle\Entity\ClientsAdresses;
    use Gba\GbaBundle\Entity\Commandes;
    use Gba\GbaBundle\Entity\Produits;


        [class CommandesController extends Controller
        {
            public function facture(Request $request)
            {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                //$random = random_bytes(10);
               // $generator = $this->container->get('security.secure_random');
                // servira à générer des chaîne aléatoires qui serviront de token
                $session = $request->getSession();
                $adresse = $session->get('adresse');
                $panier = $session->get('panier');
                $commande = array(); // on déclare un tableau commande
                $totalHT = 0;
                $totalTTC = 0;

                $facturation = $em->getRepository('GbaBundle:ClientsAdresses')->find($adresse\['facturation'\]);
                $livraison = $em->getRepository('GbaBundle:ClientsAdresses')->find($adresse\['livraison'\]);
                $produits = $em->getRepository('GbaBundle:Produits')->findArray(array_keys($session->get('panier')));

                foreach($produits as $produit)
                {
                    $prixHT = ($produit->getPrix() * $panier\[$produit->getId()\]);
                    $prixTTC = ($produit->getPrix() * $panier\[$produit->getId()\] / $produit->getTva()->getMultiplicate());
                    $totalHT += $prixHT;
                    $totalTTC += $prixTTC;

                     // tableau commande séréalisé par Doctrine
                    if (!isset($commande\['tva'\]\['%'.$produit->getTva()->getValeur()\]))
                    { $commande\['tva'\]\['%'.$produit->getTva()->getValeur()\] = round($prixTTC - $prixHT,2);}
                    else{
                    $commande\['tva'\]\['%'.$produit->getTva()->getValeur()\] += round($prixTTC - $prixHT,2);}

                    $commande\['produit'\]\[$produit->getId()\] = array('reference' => $produit->getNom(),
                                                                    'quantite' => $panier\[$produit->getId()\],
                                                                    'prixHT' => round($produit->getPrix(),2),
                                                                    'prixTTC' => round($produit->getPrix() / $produit->getTva()->getMultiplicate(),2));
                }  

                $commande\['livraison'\] = array('prenom' => $livraison->getPrenom(),
                                            'nom' => $livraison->getNom(),
                                            'telephone' => $livraison->getTelephone(),
                                            'adresse' => $livraison->getAdresse(),
                                            'cp' => $livraison->getCp(),
                                            'ville' => $livraison->getVille(),
                                            'pays' => $livraison->getPays(),
                                            'complement' => $livraison->getComplement());
                $commande\['facturation'\] = array('prenom' => $facturation->getPrenom(),
                                            'nom' => $facturation->getNom(),
                                            'telephone' => $facturation->getTelephone(),
                                            'adresse' => $facturation->getAdresse(),
                                            'cp' => $facturation->getCp(),
                                            'ville' => $facturation->getVille(),
                                            'pays' => $facturation->getPays(),
                                            'complement' => $facturation->getComplement());

                $commande\['prixHT'\] = round($totalHT, 2);
                $commande\['prixTTC'\] = round($totalTTC, 2);
               // $commande\['token'\] = bin2hex($generator->nextBytes(20));

                return $commande;
            }

              public function prepareCommandeAction(Request $request)
            {
                // on préstocke les données du panier
                $session = $request->getSession();
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                if (!$session->has('commande'))
                { $commande = new Commandes();}
                else
               {$commande = $em->getRepository('GbaBundle:Commandes')->find($session->get('commande'));}

                $commande->setDateCommande(new \DateTime());
                $commande->setDateStatut(new \DateTime());
                $commande->setClient($this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser());
                $commande->setStatut(0);
                $commande->setReferencecom(1);
                $commande->setStatut(0);
                $commande->setCommande($this->facture($request)); // on stocke toute la commande à partir de la méthode facture

                if (!$session->has('commande')) {
                    $em->persist($commande);
                    $session->set('commande',$commande);
                }

                $em->flush();

                return new Response($commande->getId());
            }
        }
```

----the Entity

```
<?php

namespace Gba\GbaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Commandes
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="commandes")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gba\GbaBundle\Repository\CommandesRepository")
 */
class Commandes
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gba\GbaUserBundle\Entity\Clients", inversedBy="commandes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="statut", type="string", length=125)
     */
    private $statut;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_commande", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCommande;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_statut", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateStatut;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="referencecom", type="string", length=125)
     */
    private $referencecom;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="commande", type="array")
     */
    private $commande;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set statut
     *
     * @param string $statut
     *
     * @return Commandes
     */
    public function setStatut($statut)
    {
        $this->statut = $statut;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get statut
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatut()
    {
        return $this->statut;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCommande
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCommande
     *
     * @return Commandes
     */
    public function setDateCommande($dateCommande)
    {
        $this->dateCommande = $dateCommande;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCommande
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateCommande()
    {
        return $this->dateCommande;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateStatut
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateStatut
     *
     * @return Commandes
     */
    public function setDateStatut($dateStatut)
    {
        $this->dateStatut = $dateStatut;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateStatut
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateStatut()
    {
        return $this->dateStatut;
    }

    /**
     * Set referencecom
     *
     * @param string $referencecom
     *
     * @return Commandes
     */
    public function setReferencecom($referencecom)
    {
        $this->referencecom = $referencecom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get referencecom
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReferencecom()
    {
        return $this->referencecom;
    }

    /**
     * Set commande
     *
     * @param array $commande
     *
     * @return Commandes
     */
    public function setCommande($commande)
    {
        $this->commande = $commande;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get commande
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCommande()
    {
        return $this->commande;
    }

    /**
     * Set client
     *
     * @param \Gba\GbaUserBundle\Entity\Clients $client
     *
     * @return Commandes
     */
    public function setClient(\Gba\GbaUserBundle\Entity\Clients $client = null)
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get client
     *
     * @return \Gba\GbaUserBundle\Entity\Clients
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }
}
```

screenshot error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt2TT.png)

Comment: Can you please tell on which line you get this error?

Answer (score 2):

Before you do `$em->flush();` the Entity is not really persisted and has no ID.

Change your code like this:

```
if (!$session->has('commande')) {
    $em->persist($commande);
    $em->flush();
    $session->set('commande',$commande);
}
```