# Can't bind form data to doctrine find function. "ORMInvalidArgumentException"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I'm trying to make a **simple guestbook in Symfony 4**, my goal is that you can **add a message** to the guestbook but before that, it needs to be **internally activated.** 
I'm now working on the activating site, but there is a problem I can't really fix. The error message is as follows:

> Binding entities to query parameters only allowed for entities that
>   have an identifier.

What i'm trying to do is, after **you've typed in the ID** of the **non-activated message** in the **Activator Form**, it takes the **data (ID)** from **the form**  that was given and **Doctrine finds** the specific **row of that ID**. Then, it changes the rows **smallint (not boolean) "isActive"** to **1**, so the Guestbook know **which messages to show.**

At **" *$message = $repository->find($id);* "** symfony couldn't bind my form data with the query parameters. I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061878/symfony-session-order-binding-entities-to-query-parameters-only-allowed-for-enti) answer but it didn't work either.

**GBActivatorController.php:**

```
  use App\Entity\Guestbook;

  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
  use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;


  class GBActivatorController extends AbstractController
    {
        public function index(Request $request)
          {

            //sets up the entity guestbook and the entitymanager from doctrine
            $guestbook = new Guestbook();
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            //get all messages
            $list = $this->getDoctrine()
              ->getRepository(Guestbook::class)
              ->findAll();

              //create form for activating a non-activated message
            $activator = $this->createFormBuilder($guestbook)
              ->add('id', NumberType::class,
                array(
                  'mapped' => false,
              ))
              ->add('activate', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Activate'])
              ->getForm();

            $activator->handleRequest($request);

              /*when the submit button is clicked, get the data and
               find the row with the specific id that was given.*/
              if($activator->isSubmitted())
              {
                //gets the data from the form
                $id = $activator->getData();

                //sets up repository, so i dont need to type it again
                $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Guestbook::class);

                //(should) find the row
                $message = $repository->find($id);
                //activates row. (isActive = 1 instead of isActive = 0)
                $message->setIsActive(1);

                //persist and then execute to table
                $entityManager->persist($message);
                $entityManager->flush();
              }

            //renders the template
            return $this->render('GBActivator.html.twig', array(
              'list' => $list,
              'activator' => $activator->createView()
              ));

          }
    }
```

**Entity/Guestbook.php:**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\GuestbookRepository")
 */
class Guestbook
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $text;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function setId(Array $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getText(): ?string
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    public function setText(string $text): self
    {
        $this->text = $text;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsActive(): ?int
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function setIsActive(int $isActive): self
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: setId(Array $id) - why Array?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Eakethet.
My problem was that i demanded an array instead of a string. Stupid me. I changed

```
public function setId(Array $id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

to

```
public function setId(string $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
```

Comment: Do you realize that if you `$form = (new Form())->setHydrator(new DoctrineObject())->bind(new Guestbook())` you create a new Form, set the Doctrine Hydrator and an object (can be replaced with existing for editing/"activating"). After `isValid()` you can then simply `$entity = $form->getObject()` (before validation `$form->setData($activator->getData())`) to get your Guestbook fully hydrated during the `isValid` by the DoctrineObject hydrator class. No need to do mappings and fuss about ID's being set or not. Posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54347365/1155833) yesterday. - cont.

Comment: cont. - though for ZF, it might help you out a bit. Looks like it might save you a bunch of work.